# Find trace and determinant of matrix $A$ such that $A^2 = I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials, cayley-hamilton

I have a $ 2\times 2$ matrix $A$, where $A^2 = I$.

So the eigenvalues are  $\lambda= \pm1$ .

**I need to find its trace and determinant.** There's no mention of upper or lower triangular matrix, therefore, the formulas for Trace and
determinant := product of eigenvalues can't be used here.

The other part does give some specific information but I wonder is there any way to solve the first part because that's how it should be solved.

*b) If the first row is (3,−1), what is the second row?*

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sum and product formulas for trace and determinant work just fine for non-triangular matrices. As for the second part, just define the second row as $(a, b)$ and set up a 2x2 system from the trace and determinant.

Comment: If you are given no information about $A$ besides the fact that it is a $2\times 2$ matrix with $A^2=I$, that is not enough to determine its trace and determinant.

Comment: @EricWofsey Assuming $A$ is not a trivial solution to the equation (meaning $\pm I$) we actually can determine these values: consider $(A + I)(A - I) = (A - I)(A + I) = 0.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan: Sure, but we are not given any such assumption!

Comment: @EricWofsey True, but given the format I think it's likely that this was a question for an assignment, and that assumption was likely written in the full form for part (a). (although that is a bit speculative) In any case we can use these values in part (b) without restriction since we have the top row.

Comment: Note: $ \lambda \in \{-1,1\} \implies trace(A) \in \{-2,0,2\}$ and $\det(A) \in \{-1,1\}  $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that $A^2-I=0$ means precisely that $A$ is diagonalisable with its set of eigenvalues *contained in* the set $\{-1,1\}$ of (simple) roots of $X^2-1$. The multiset of roots for the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A$, which has size $2$, can then be one of $\{\!\{-1,-1\}\!\}$, $\{\!\{-1,1\}\!\}$, and $\{\!\{1,1\}\!\}$. The trace and determinant are respectively the sum and the product of that multiset, giving three possibilities $(-2,1)$, $(0,-1)$, $(2,1)$ for the pair $(\operatorname{tr}A,\det A)$.

Since being diagonalisable with a single eigenvalue$~\lambda$ means being equal to $\lambda I$, the outer two possibilities only occur for $-I$ respectively for $I$, and so they can be excluded for question b).

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Here is a very direct approach. Let
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then find $A^2$ and explicitly set to $I$ -- that gives you 4 equations in 4 unknowns...

After you discover the needed relationships between $a,b,c,d$, note that $\det A = ab - bc$ and $\mathrm{tr} A = a+d$...

---

**UPDATE**

Many comments below claim it is a hard system to solve. Here is my approach:
$$
A^2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a^2+bc & b(a+d) \\
c(a+d) & d^2+bc
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
= I,
$$
so $b(a+d) = 0 = c(a+d)$. Hence, either $b=c=0$ or $a=-d$.

In the first case, $a,d = \pm 1$ and $b,c = 0$, a fairly narrow set of choices.

In the second case, imposing the upper left and lower right equations,
$$a^2 = 1 - bc = d^2 \iff a = -d = \pm \sqrt{1-bc},$$
which also leaves a very narrow margin of choices.

Comment: It's probably not going to be pretty. There are, after all, three possible traces and two possible determinants.

Comment: The system isn't linear, so there's no guarantee that the solution is unique. And in this case, it's not: at the bare minimum you have $A = I$ or $A = -I.$

Comment: Well actually you can triangularize the matrix so you only have $\pm1$ on the diagonal entries and an unknown $x$ in the top right entry. Solving for $A^2=I$ leaves few options after that and it is much easier to deal with than $4$ unknowns

Comment: Just did it, it is quite easy.

Comment: Responding to the update: my apologies if I came off as a bit dismissive before but the wording "4 equations in 4 variables" made me think you meant you were solving for a unique solution, as you might have in a 4x4 linear system. (assuming invertibility) In any case this is a pretty sensible way of going about it but if they wanted the trace/determinant for the non-trivial solutions anyway then this is still more involved than is really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

By Cayley-Hamilton, if $A\ne\pm I$, then we have that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^2-\mathrm{tr}(A)x+\det(A)=x^2-1$. Thus $\mathrm{tr}(A)=0$ and $\det(A)=-1$.

Comment: What about $-I$? Also the matrix in your last paragraph does not satisfy $A^2=I$, unless $a=0$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. BTW, $-I$ does have non-distinct eigenvalues, so...

Comment: Excuse me, but I neither know what a non-distinct number is, nor why this is relevant (neither OP nor your answer mention non-distinct numbers). The cases $A=I$ and $A=-I$ are _not exceptions_ to the Cayley-Hamilton theorem (which has no exceptions). But what you say is simply not correct. C-H says that $\chi_A$ is an annihilating polynomial, not that any annihilating polynomial (even if unitary of the correct degree) is the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Cayley-Hamilton says that given a matrix $A$ and its characteristic polynomial $f$, we have $f(A)=0$. Writing $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$, together with $A^2-I=0$ we obtain $aA+(b+1)I=0$, which implies $a=0$ and $b=-1$ unless $A=\pm I$. (Sorry, I mentioned non-distinct eigenvalues previously, which I edited out, since it is just equivalent to $A=\pm I$.)

Answer (score 2):

Do the two cases $A=\pm \,I$ separately.  Henceforth, $A\ne\pm \,I.$ Let $f(x)=x^2-1.$
$f(A)$ is zero and neither proper divisor of $f(x)$ annihilates $A.$  Thus $f(x)$ is the minimal
polynomial of $A$ and consequently the characteristic polynomial of $A.$ By the usual formula,
the trace of $A$ is zero and $|A|=-1.$